# Unauthorized endpoint error even though the remote site has been added

Tags: oauth2, custom-domain, remote-site-settings

I'm getting the following error authenticating with the UN/PW oauth2 flow (I redacted the actual domain name):

`Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://CUSTOM_DOMAIN.cs32.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token`

I have added a remote site setting for this domain but the error is persisting. Has anyone else experienced this doing oauth2 callouts to orgs with custom login domains?

**NOTE:** this org does have this checkbox enabled `Prevent login from https://test.salesforce.com`.

EDIT:

```
    if (customer.thisOrg.domain_override__c!=null) {
        req.setEndpoint(customer.thisOrg.domain_override__c+'/services/oauth2/token');
    }
    else {
        //check to see if type is sandbox or production/developer
        if(customer.thisOrg.type__c == 'Sandbox'){
            req.setEndpoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
        }
        else{
            req.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
        }   
    }
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody('grant_type=password'+
        '&client_id='+' CLIENT_ID'+
        '&client_secret='+'CLIENT_SECRET'+
        '&username='+customer.thisOrg.username__c+
        '&password='+customer.thisOrg.password__c
    );

    httpResponse res = new httpResponse();

    try {
        // send request     
        Http http = new Http();
        // capture response
        res = http.send(req);
        system.debug('authentication response: '+ res.getBody());
    }
    catch (exception e) {
        system.debug('error authenticating with customer: '+ e.getMessage());
        customer.log += '\n\n error authenticating: ' + e.getMessage(); 
          return null;
    }
```

Comment: have you added `https://CUSTOM_DOMAIN.cs32.my.salesforce.com/` in remote site.. If yes also try to add `https://test.salesforce.com`

Comment: yep, I did. I included that in my question. I'm able to authenticate fine with other orgs both sandboxes and production. EDIT: yes test.salesforce.com is in there as well.

Comment: Are you using SOAP API callout?

Comment: @Ratan no I'm not

Comment: Phil what is your endpoint you are using?

Comment: @Ratan I'm authenticating against the custom domain above. Thats the domain they use to login, and logins from test.salesforce.com are disabled for the org.

Comment: prevent login checkbox doesn't matter in this case. can you post your code as well ?

Comment: @PhilB pretty redundant check, but hope you have used 'https' itself not 'http'. Thanks

Comment: @Stygon, yes I am

Comment: @Himanshu - added code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the Remote Site is case sensitive (not sure why) so if you encounter this error please verify the casing.